# algoritmos de programacion logica

Tags: nodejs, algoritmos, real-time, notification

hola comunidad **stackoverflow** espero no los aburra con tanta explicación tratare de ser detallista para que puedan entender mi problema. Necesito de su ayudad para crear un algoritmo, no estoy pidiendo que hagan mi trabajo si no mas bien que me den algunas ideas de como puedo lograr lo que necesito hacer os explico tengo un proyecto en **php** y **nodejs** que a la vez uso  y la libreria **socket.io** de **nodejs** para las notificaciones en tiempo real el cual me trabaja muy bien el envío de mensajes y notificaciones en tiempo real es perfecto por así decirlo hasta aquí todo bien.

la cosa es que yo solo se mandar mensajes o notificaciones a un cliente en especifico identificado por su id de session de **php** ejemplo cuando el usuario inicia session si el usuario introdujo sus datos correctos el **ajax** recoje el id de session en una variable **var** id lo manda de esta forma a `window.location.href="home.php"+id` en el **home.php** 
su session es guardada en un atributo data de html por ejemplo `<i id="show_notifications" data-id_user="<?php echo$_GET["id"]?>">` este es el id de session de el usuario que proviene desde **login.php** que luego mas adelante me servirá para mostrar las notificaciones en tiempo real en breve  les explico como.

un ejemplo cuando yo por ejemplo doy like a la foto de un usuario es ejecutar un codigo javascript que envié atraves de `socket.io` la información de ese like por ejemplo envío los siguientes datos al servidor **nodejs** `{id de el usuario al que le di like:id_user,el id de el post al que le di like:post_id }` el servidor **nodejs** recibe esos datos los manda para atrás y yo los proceso de esta manera para que llegue la notificación a esa persona que le di like ejemplo...

```
     socket.on("message_from_server",function(data){//listen nodeServer response

            /*la variable actual_user mediante attr captura el id de session actual
               al que se enviara dicha notificacion*/

             var actual_user=$("#show_notifications").attr("data-id_user");

               /*con una condición le decimos que si la variable actual user
                  es igual al id que recibimos de la respuesta de el servidor
                  me ejecute la siguiente instruccion 
                */
                 if(actual_user==data.id_user){

                  /*
                 la etiqueta i que contiene el id show_notifications esta oculta
                 y cuando se ejecuta el código para la notification
                 la mostramos con algunos estilos para que el usuario
                  vea en tiempo real la notifiaction
                  */
                    $("#show_notifications").show();//muestra la etiqueta que contiene la notification
                 }
            })
```

como verán el código no es una cosa de el otro mundo es sencillo y funciona a la perfección por supuesto que falta mas información de alguna cosas de los script php y como obtengo los datos que envío a `nodejs` pero es algo sencillo también solo no quería hostigarlos con tanta información, ahora bien me ha surgido la necesidad de enviar una notificación por ejemplo a 5 ,10,50,100 usuarios al mismo tiempo como podría yo hacer eso? es decir si por ejemplo yo quiero enviar esa notificación a todos los usuarios que son mis  seguidores en mi pagina de que yo le di like a "pedro" por ejemplo, como podría yo implementar eso por que básicamente si yo tengo por ejemplo **1000**,**2000** o **20,000** seguidores de que manera o cual seria la mejor manera de yo enviar  una notificación de esa magnitud con **nodejs**? esa es mi duda espero no los aya aburrido con tanta explicación gracias y si alguien me puede ayudar o darme una idea o tips se los agradecería saludos!

Comment: Y cómo envías las notificaciones o mensajes desde el servidor?

Comment: @Mario L te refieres al servidor node?

Comment: Claro, es que tu pregunta es algo amplia, no sé si no tienes seguro cómo enviar desde el servidor las notificaciones a tu x cantidad de seguidores, o si no sabes como cada cliente debe recibir esas notificaciones

Comment: voy a editar la pregunta para que veas el proceso de como se comunica el servidor con el cliente

Comment: podrias epesifiacr un poco mas @JackNavaRow a que te refieres con crear un tipo de mensaje ? recuerad que estoy usando la libreria de socket.io

Comment: Hola @andygibbs ¿Pudiste resolver tu problema? Estoy en una situación similar.